# Problem with paging in telerik Radgrid when databinded from ServerSide

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, radgrid, telerik-grid

I have two radgrid , for the first radgrid i am binding the data from serverside , and for the second radgrid i am binding the data through sqldatasource from clientside.
 The radgrid2 for which i bind the data through clientside,pagination property works fine , and my grid gets refresh each time.
 But the major problem is when bind the radgrid from serverside my pagination property is not working,is their any property i have to set for pagination to work when i am binding the data from serverside, can any one please help to figure out the problem.

This is my aspx page code which contains the radgrid

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RadGridRefreshTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="RadGridTest.RadGridRefreshTest" enableEventValidation="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
        </telerik:RadScriptManager>
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowPaging="true"  PageSize="10" AllowCustomPaging="True" onpageindexchanged="RadGrid1PageIndexChanged" >
        <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric"  />
        </telerik:RadGrid>

        second grid
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2" runat="server" CellSpacing="0" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource" GridLines="None" 
            onpageindexchanged="RadGrid2PageIndexChanged" >
<MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" >
<CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF"></CommandItemSettings>

<RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column">
<HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
</RowIndicatorColumn>

<ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column">
<HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
</ExpandCollapseColumn>

    <Columns>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CustomerID" 
            FilterControlAltText="Filter CustomerID column" HeaderText="CustomerID" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerID" UniqueName="CustomerID">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CompanyName" 
            FilterControlAltText="Filter CompanyName column" HeaderText="CompanyName" 
            SortExpression="CompanyName" UniqueName="CompanyName">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ContactName" 
            FilterControlAltText="Filter ContactName column" HeaderText="ContactName" 
            SortExpression="ContactName" UniqueName="ContactName">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ContactTitle" 
            FilterControlAltText="Filter ContactTitle column" HeaderText="ContactTitle" 
            SortExpression="ContactTitle" UniqueName="ContactTitle">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Address" 
            FilterControlAltText="Filter Address column" HeaderText="Address" 
            SortExpression="Address" UniqueName="Address">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="City" 
            FilterControlAltText="Filter City column" HeaderText="City" 
            SortExpression="City" UniqueName="City">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Region" 
            FilterControlAltText="Filter Region column" HeaderText="Region" 
            SortExpression="Region" UniqueName="Region">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PostalCode" 
            FilterControlAltText="Filter PostalCode column" HeaderText="PostalCode" 
            SortExpression="PostalCode" UniqueName="PostalCode">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Country" 
            FilterControlAltText="Filter Country column" HeaderText="Country" 
            SortExpression="Country" UniqueName="Country">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Phone" 
            FilterControlAltText="Filter Phone column" HeaderText="Phone" 
            SortExpression="Phone" UniqueName="Phone">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Fax" 
            FilterControlAltText="Filter Fax column" HeaderText="Fax" SortExpression="Fax" 
            UniqueName="Fax">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    </Columns>

<EditFormSettings>
<EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column"></EditColumn>
</EditFormSettings>
</MasterTableView>

<FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False"></FilterMenu>

<HeaderContextMenu CssClass="GridContextMenu GridContextMenu_Default"></HeaderContextMenu>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString2 %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Customers]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code behind file where i am writing the code for grid binding using datasource

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using Telerik.Web.UI;
using Telerik.Web.Data;


namespace RadGridTest
{
    public partial class RadGridRefreshTest : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString ="data source=ADMIN-PC1;uid=sa;password=sql;database=NorthWind";
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("CustOrders");
            SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Customers", con);
            da1.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Customers");
            da1.Fill(ds);
            RadGrid1.DataSource = ds;
            RadGrid1.DataBind();
        }
        protected void RadGrid1PageIndexChanged(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridPageChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = e.NewPageIndex;
            int current = RadGrid1.CurrentPageIndex;
        }

        protected void RadGrid2PageIndexChanged(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridPageChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = e.NewPageIndex;
            int current = RadGrid1.CurrentPageIndex;
        }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822075/cannot-identify-selected-page-in-telerik-grid-i-need-selected-page-to-be-underl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem setting the RadGrid.DataSource to a Linq query.  I'll tell you a few of the things I tried, and what I eventually had to move to.

First off, if

```
 AllowCustomPaging = True
```

Then the default paging is overridden.  Try setting either the AllowPaging to true, or AllowCustomPaging to true, but not both.  Telerik controls are fickle! :)

I tried setting up paging inside of the MasterTableView as well, to no avail
I also added AllowViewstate and made sure the control was linked to the RadAjaxManager

```
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid1">
       <UpdatedControls>
             <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" />
       </UpdatedControls>
 </telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

Neither worked for me, but give it a shot.

I eventually used a Listview and setup the templated columns for the data inside, and enabled paging and it all worked just fine.  I know this isn't a direct answer, but maybe it will give you some new ideas.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and it was because I had AllowCustomPaging AND AllowPaging both set to true.  Thank you for your wisdom!

Comment: Telerik have example code showing both AllowPaging and AllowCustomPaging set to true: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/paging/custom-paging/defaultcs.aspx
Not sure this is new functionality since your post.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that I had both `AllowPaging="true"` and`AllowCustomPaging="true"` in my grid.  Removing one of these fixed the issue.