# Cannot identify selected page in telerik grid. I need selected page to be underlined. Help me in this

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid, telerik-mvc, radgridview

For my telerik radgrid I am using numeric pages. I can see the page numbers. But I am not able to identify the selected page. All the page numbers remais alike after selecting the page. I need the selected page number to be underlined. Help me in this

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

There is a control called **PagerTextFormat** that allows you to display *current page, total page number, total record number* and etc.

After adding your grid (radgrid), you can manually define a PagerStyle block in aspx side and put your code like below:

```
<PagerStyle PagerTextFormat="{0} Current Page: {1} - Total Number of Pages: {2}"/>
```

You probably have that block since you have already explained you are using numeric controls. You just need to add the above definition to the block.

Now, let me explain all those numbers:

- {0} ->  indicates where pager buttons would appear
- {1} ->  displays current page number
- {2} ->  displays total number of pages

It's not putting a line under the selected page number, but I think you can benefit from it. Check [this telerik page](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/functionality/paging/changing-the-default-pager/using-pagertextformat) to find more. There are different versions and examples.

Hope this helps! Good luck!